# C# WinForm DataGridView Adding Unbound Column Breaks CellFormatting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have several DataGridViews that use the CellFormatting event handler to convert database ID values into user-friendly display strings.  However, one of these DataGridViews has an added DataGridViewButtonColumn to allow the user to perform some data analysis on the row data. The problem: if I add the Button column to the DataGridView at run-time, the grid displays the raw database ID value rather than the user-friendly string ([image: see image 1]).  If I comment out the logic that adds the unbound column, the grid displays the user-friendly string ([image: see image 2]).

EDIT: Here is the CellFormatting code:

```
private void GridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.Value != null)
   {
       int    experimentId = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value);
       string displayValue = ConvertToExperiment(experimentId);

       e.Value             = displayValue;
       e.FormattingApplied = true;
   }
}
```

and here is the initialization code that adds the button column:

```
private void LoadExperimentHistory()
{
    string selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM ExperimentLog";

    SQLiteCommand     sqlCommand     = new SQLiteCommand(selectCommand, databaseConnection);
    SQLiteDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        historyDataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

        if (historyDataTable != null)
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = historyDataTable;
            dataGridView.Columns["ID"          ].Visible    = false;
            dataGridView.Columns["ExperimentId"].HeaderText = "Experiment";
            dataGridView.Columns["StartDate"   ].HeaderText = "Start Date";

            if (dataGridView.Columns["Analysis"] == null)
            {
                DataGridViewButtonColumn analysisColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
                {
                    Name                        = "Analysis",
                    Text                        = "Run Analysis",
                    UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true,
                    FlatStyle                   = FlatStyle.Standard
                };

                analysisColumn.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                dataGridView.Columns.Add(analysisColumn);
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageForm messageForm = new MessageForm(exception.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        messageForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

SECOND EDIT:

While I agree that it would have been helpful to post the CellFormatting() code to start, I still think that this is a completely reasonable question/problem: why in the world does adding an unbound column break the very simple logic in CellFormatting()?

Comment: If the code in your `CellFormatting` event handler doesn't work then that code is wrong, but you seem to have decided that showing us the code that's wrong is not a good way to help us determine how to fix it. My guess would be that you are using the index of the column you want to format but that index is different after adding the unbound column. I shouldn't have to guess though.

Comment: Can you show us the Code? An [mcve]

Comment: If the code in the CellFormatting event handler is wrong, why does it work, unchanged, if I comment out the initialization code that adds the Button column?

Comment: The code that sets the unbound Column is missing. You have: `if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.Value != null)`, but it looks like that Column should have index = `0`, given that it's the first one. Maybe adding the unbound Column resets the index to its natural `0` index. Or you inserted the unbound Column and set its `DisplayIndex` -- This is something you easily spot while debugging your code. Or, simply, don't validate the Column by Index but by Name.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the code that creates the DataGridView at *Design-Time* from the `InitializeComponent()`

Create the DataGridView's columns at *Run-Time* in the `Form_Load()` code.

The columns indexes are obviously overlapping and its easier to solve it in one place and at *Run-Time* gives you more control.

Comment: I disagree. You can easily refer to a column via the field created by the designer or by `DisplayIndex`, so there's no need to change what the designer is doing.

Comment: I'll update my answer if we can see the code. There's a conflict between Design-Time and Run-Time and is probably caused by the CellFormating. This answer leads OP to solve it in one place or the other. At Run-Time you have the benefit of creating controls dynamically - which is causing the problem.